# Como mandar um F11 em uma pagina aberta no IE8.0

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou com um problema, a empresa que trabalho usa o navegador versão IE 8.0 no windows XP, eu tenho um codigo que envia um comando F11 em javascript funciona em qualquer navegador porém nesse especifico não roda vocês tem alguma sugestão para que eu posso está fazendo para funcionar o código abaixo no IE 8.0

```
function requestFullScreen() {


    var el = document.body;
    //alert(el);
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen  || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;
    //alert(requestMethod);
    if(requestMethod) {
    alert("TESTE1");
    // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(el);

    }else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject == "undefined"){
        //alert("TESTE2");
        // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

        if(wscript !== null) {
            x = window.innerWidth
            y = window.innerHeight;
            alert(x+' - '+y);
            if(y == 916){
                wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
            }else if(y == 1005){
                wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
            }else{

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no IE8 + XP não era outro atalho? alt + [alguma coisa]

Comment: Então o problema que estou tendo no código é que ele não me mostra as dimensões da tela width e height no alert que está no código na variável x y

Comment: alt + enter (ainda funciona no Edge também)